# What is the name of this plant with large and lush leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

My uncle has this plant in northern NSW Australia. Just wondering if anyone knows what it is?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a *Calathea*. A quick image search yielded *[Calathea orbifolia](https://garden.org/plants/photo/251981/)* which looks like a good match.

Comment: How did you do the image search?